# splinter: how to add chrome options?

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, splinter

I'm using splinter(v0.7.3) for web testing under linux, while on chrome, the default sample code can not running:

```
from splinter import Browser
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display

d = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
d.start()

b = Browser('chrome')
b.visit('http://www.google.com')
b.quit()

d.stop()
```

While running, I got the exception like this:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: chrome not reachable
```

And I test the same function in selenium with some chrome option added:

```
from selenium import web driver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display

d = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
d.start()

opt = Options()
opt.add_argument('--disable-setuid-sandbox')
b = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=opt)
b.get('http://www.google.com')
b.quit()

d.stop()
```

This works ok, the difference is the `--disable-setuid-sandbox` option added to chrome driver, if the option not add, there would be a zombie `chrome-sandbox` process under `chromium-browser`.

The problem here is, I don't know how to pass a `chrome.options.Option` instance to `splinter.Browser()`, I browsed the implementation under `splinter/driver/webdriver/chrome.py`, it seems that there is no entry to pass such a instance to `splinter.Browser()`. Is there some other way to pass options to chrome driver?

Answer (score 2):

Create a new instance of `BaseWebDriver` and set `.driver` with an instance of the Chrome driver. This example starts Chrome maximized:

```py
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from splinter.driver.webdriver import BaseWebDriver, WebDriverElement

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--start-maximized')

browser = BaseWebDriver()
browser.driver = Chrome(chrome_options=options)

browser.visit('https://www.google.com')
```

Comment: Interresting, but I tried that and I had annoying issue, desparatly search for a way to control Chrome language as chromedriver doesn't take defined preferences difined. My ubuntu locales are in french so it's like chrome is install with french as default language and I can't control this from splinter which make my tests failed...

Answer (score 1):

The only way I could ever do this was by using the `add_argument` method with `selenium.webdriver.ChromeOptions` like so:

```
from selenium.webdriver import ChromeOptions
from splinter import Browser

chrome_options = ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument(your_argument)

b=Browser("chrome", options=chrome_options)
b.visit('http://www.google.com')
b.quit()
```

so in your code would be:

```
from splinter import Browser
from selenium.webdriver import ChromeOptions
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display #I'm not certain what this is...

d = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
d.start()

chrome_options = ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('disable-setuid-sandbox')

b = Browser('chrome')
b.visit('http://www.google.com')
b.quit()

d.stop()
```

Note: I was unable to test this with your argument specifically because I recently broke my GRUB so I am stuck in windows, and the `disable-setuid-sandbox` option is linux-only. However, I have been using this method with the `headless` argument for a while.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure that this will work but I just looked at the docs for splinter and it says.

> You can also pass additional arguments that correspond to Selenium DesiredCapabilities arguments.

Looking into the sourcecode of Splinter calling Browser can take some arguments. These arguments will then be passed to create an Instance of the Chrome WebDriver. So I went to the selenium sourcecode and saw the constructor looks like this:

```
def __init__(self, executable_path="chromedriver", port=0,
                 chrome_options=None, service_args=None,
                 desired_capabilities=None, service_log_path=None):
```

There is a parameter for chrome_options so it should be possible to pass it using this parameter. So if I'm correct this should work fine:

```
opt = Options()
opt.add_argument('--disable-setuid-sandbox')
b = Browser(browser='chrome', chrome_options=opt)
```

**Edit**
Alternatively you could pass the options as desired capabilities aswell:

```
opt = Options()
opt.add_argument('--disable-setuid-sandbox')
dc = opt.to_capabilities()
b = Browser(browser='chrome', desired_capabilities=dc)
```

Comment: Would you show me the link? I searched the splinter [doc](https://splinter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), there is a `desired_capabilities`, but only for firefox, unfortunatly, the `chrome_options` not available for my current splinter version(0.7.3).

Comment: @coanor It is in the doc for Remote WebDiver (https://splinter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/drivers/remote.html) I don't think it'll differ from the Chrome WebDriver as it both creates an instance of the same Browser class. Did you try my suggestion?

Comment: @coanor Here is the sourcecode for the Browser class https://github.com/cobrateam/splinter/blob/master/splinter/browser.py. As you can see it does little more than creating a ChromeWebDriver and passing the *args and **kwargs. So that means you can pass the arguments that are used by the selenium WebDriver which is here https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/py/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py#L34

Comment: Under 0.7.3 (the github master branch version), there is no such `chrome_options` parameters, and any additional parameters cause syntax error, plz see the source code in [github](https://github.com/cobrateam/splinter/blob/master/splinter/driver/webdriver/chrome.py#L17)

Comment: @coanor Oh I see I've made a mistake because it doesn't call the selenium WebDriver, it call the splinter WebDriver. Give me a sec and I'll see if I can find a way.

Comment: @coanor There is no easy way to do this. All I can think of is making your own Browser and WebDriver classes and using these to start the browser yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on a fork of splinter for the past couple weeks, you can check out my dev branch if you want. I have added this and other features.

Options can be passed as a list to the `chrome_options` parameter

```
from splinter import Browser

options = ['--start-maximized', '--disable-setuid-sandbox']

with Browser('chrome', chrome_options=options) as browser:
    browser.visit('http://www.google.com')
```

**Edit:**

So it turns out this was possible with splinter all along just using `**kwargs` which passes the various available options to the selenium driver(s). For example:

```
from splinter import Browser

options = {'chrome_options':['--start-maximized', '--disable-setuid-sandbox']}

with Browser('chrome', **options) as browser:
    browser.visit('http://www.google.com')
```